# Hyper-V 2012 R2 creates multiple vEthernet adapters

Tags: virtual-machines, vswitch

on our Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V Free server, which will host the VM now running on an ESXi, I messed up launching twice the

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapter
```

cmdlet. These are the steps I took:

create a team

```
New-NetLbfoTeam -Name TeamTrunk -TeamMembers NIC1,NIC2 -LoadBalancingAlgorithm HyperVPort -TeamingMode SwitchIndependent
```

create a virtual switch

```
New-VMSwitch -Name vSwitchTrunk -AllowManagementOS $false -NetAdapterName TeamTrunk
```

created the vEthernet

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name Cloud -SwitchName
vSwitchTrunk Add-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name Office -SwitchName vSwitchTrunk
```

with the purpose to assign VLANs with

```
Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -ManagementOS -Access -VlanId 9 -VMNetworkAdapterName Cloud
Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -ManagementOS -Access -VlanId 10  -VMNetworkAdapterName Office
```

As mentioned, I've launched **twice** Add-VMNetworkAdapter.
Now, querying the system with *Get-NetAdapter*, it shows

```
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex
----                      --------------------                    -------
vEthernet (Cloud) #3  Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #9          112
vEthernet (Cloud) #2  Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #8          108
vEthernet (Cloud) #1  Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #7          104
vEthernet (Cloud)     Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #6          100
vEthernet (Office) #3 Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #5          96
vEthernet (Office) #2 Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #4          90
vEthernet (Office) #1 Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3          84
vEthernet (Office)    Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2          78
```

I've tried to remove the adapters, with the cmdlet

```
Remove-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name xyz
```

which removes all the adapters. If I re-execute the cmdlet *Add-VMNetworkAdapter*, it creates multiple vEthernet adapters.

How can I make it back to create only one vEthernet adapter?

Any idea?
I can reboot the server with no problems.

Thank you in advance.